# Azure reverse proxy

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api

One of the projects I'm working on hides the url to the api. 
It uses a url rewriter and reverse proxy.
So if you look at the requests if Fidler, you will see 
dev-ui.azurewebsites.net/api/products instead of dev-api.azurewebsites.net/api/products

I'm trying to set it up on a similar project but keeping getting 502 The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process.

Is there another way I can achieve this?

Comment: if you are using azure webapp (and it appears you are), i dont think you can rewrite url to another domain, and why would you do that anyway?

Comment: Yes, it is currently be done on a couple projects. Its an api facade to hide the underlying api.